# js - one catch for two promises

Tags: javascript, promise

i am making an app and since i am new to promises i am struggling with promises. Here is my code:

```
let error = null;
let login = $('#inputLogin').val();

let errorCheck = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if ( login === "" ) { error = "no login!"; }
    if ( error !== null ) { 
        error = { status: false, reason: error, result: null }; 
        reject(error) 
    } else { 
        resolve() 
    }
})

let authUser = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    $.ajax( 
        {   
            url: "src/game/Action.php", 
            method: "POST",
            data: { action: "createUser", login: $('#inputLogin').val(), pass: $('#inputPass').val() }
        }
    ).done(function (data) {
        let response = JSON.parse(data);
        if ( !response.status ) {
            reject(response);
        } else {
            resolve()
        }
    })
})

errorCheck.then(function() {
    console.log('no error.. go on..')
    return authUser;
}).
then(function () {
    console.log('everything is fine')
}).
catch(function (error) {
    console.log('error: ' + error.status)
})
```

As you can see there are two verifications: first one checks if login field is not empty. If it is empty it creates an object with status and reason variables, and promise is rejected. If it is ok (no error occured) it begins to check async ajax call theat checks if user is already in database. This returns JSON string which is parsed to object similiar to error object. If this object's status is false it also rejects its own promise. Otherwise it is all ok and user has been added to database.

Unfortunatelly this code is not working as intended:
It checks `authUser` even if `errorCheck` fails but i guess `errorCheck` on error should call catch and stop executing anything else.

What i want to achieve is:
if error happens (error returns false) - go to catch. If there is no error, go authenticate user. If user returns false - go to catch. Otherwise task is completed.

Any help would be more than appreciated.

PS: i also need to mention that is authUser returns false i get an error in console:
`Uncaught (in promise) {status: false, reason: "user already in db", result: null}`

Comment: Do you have a specific purpose for using a Promise while checking the `login` variable value? That is a purely synchronous activity as it is written and the Promise is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the Promise that makes the ajax request inside a function that you call when your error check passes. The function inside the promise is going to run as soon as you define the promise. This is why the auth check is happening every time. For example this runs the `console.log` immediately:

```js
var promsie = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log("this runs")
})
```

You want something more like this:

```
function authUser() {
    return  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
        $.ajax( )
        // ...etc
    })
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
errorCheck.then(function() {
    console.log('no error.. go on..')
    return authUser()
})
```

Two other things:

I don't use jquery much, but I believe `$.ajax()` returns a promise, so I don't think you don't need to wrap it in another. You can just `return $.ajax(//...etc)` from the function.

Since your login check code isn't asynchronous, you don't really need the promise, you can just make a function that returns a boolean and save yourself some lines of code and complication.

Comment: all the things implemented did the job - thank you - i accept your answer !